# Can not scroll in chrome using jQuery mousewheel plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am building a vertical scrolling website where the mousewheel is used to scroll to each section. However, the content only scrolls when my cursor is over the main content and not the white space in Chrome. Works perfectly fine in Firefox, and even IE, though.

Here's the test site: http://agilebuilds.com/media/test-site/

Comment: Can you add the relevant code snippet to your post?

Comment: Always include the relevant code to your question. Future visitors can't see the linked code, when your "test-site" is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the cause of the difference is between the browsers, but I got it to work on Chrome by adding a `div` element surrounding your `#wrapper` div like so:

```html
<div width='100%'>
<div id="wrapper">
  ...
</div><!--/#wrapper-->
</div>
```

I assume this makes a difference because `#wrapper` has the style `max-width: 960px;`, so to be safe you might want to set the new `div` element's width to 100%.